# how to rewrite this one long url to make it short using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link on my website menu 
http://www.website.com/index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc

and I am trying to make this into http://www.website.com/store_name

I almost spent all day trying to make this work, and looked all over the web and tried different examples out there but couldn't get it to work.

I don't know why this is not working

```
RewriteRule ^store_name/?$ index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc [NC,L]
```

Any idea?? I would appreciate any input, thank you.

------here is the whole htaccess --------

```
RewriteEngine On

# reserve XE Layout Template Source File (*.html)
RewriteRule ^(layouts|m.layouts)/(.+)\.html$ - [L,F]
# reserve XE Template Source Files (*.html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/modules/editor/
RewriteRule /(skins|m.skins)/(.+)\.html$ - [L,F]

# store_name rewrite
RewriteRule ^store_name/?$ index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc [NC,L]

# conf, query, schema
RewriteRule ^(modules|addons|widgets)/(.+)/(conf|queries|schemas)/(.+)\.xml$ ./index.php [L]

# static files
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/files/(member_extra_info|attach|cache|faceOff)/(.*) ./files/$2/$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(files|modules|widgets|widgetstyles|layouts|m.layouts|addons)/(.*) ./$2/$3 [L]

# rss , blogAPI
RewriteRule ^(rss|atom)$ ./index.php?module=rss&act=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(rss|atom|api)$ ./index.php?mid=$1&act=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(rss|atom|api)$ ./index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&act=$3 [L]

# trackback
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ ./index.php?document_srl=$1&key=$2&act=trackback [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ ./index.php?mid=$1&document_srl=$2&key=$3&act=trackback [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ ./index.php?vid=$1&document_srl=$2&key=$3&act=trackback [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/trackback$ ./index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&document_srl=$3&key=$4&act=trackback [L]

# document permanent link
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ ./index.php?document_srl=$1 [L,QSA]

# mid link
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ ./index.php?mid=$1 [L,QSA]
# mid + document link
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ ./index.php?mid=$1&document_srl=$2 [L,QSA]

# vid + mid link
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ ./index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2 [L,QSA]
# vid + mid + document link
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ ./index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&document_srl=$3 [L,QSA]

# mid + entry title
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/entry/(.+)$ ./index.php?mid=$1&entry=$2 [L,QSA]
# vid + mid + entry title
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/entry/(.+)$ ./index.php?vid=$1&mid=$2&entry=$3 [L,QSA]

#shop / vid / [category|product] / identifier
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)$ ./index.php?act=route&vid=$1&type=$2&identifier=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite and .htacces are enabled.

Comment: thank you for your response, they are both enabled. I have other rewriterules in htaccess that's working

Comment: So when you type this URL in your browser, nothing happens? `http://www.website.com/store_name` post all of your rules.

Comment: I just uploaded everything in htaccess file

Comment: @user3023177: Do you get 404 when you open `http://www.website.com/store_name` in browser?

Comment: no, http://www.website.com/store_name comes out fine but it's not ordered, so I have to use  http://www.website.com/index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc but url looks ugly and hard to remember for user, looks like 

RewriteRule ^store_name/?$ index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc [NC,L]

doesn't have any affect

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^store_name/(.+) index.php?mid=store_name&sort_index=store&order_type=asc [NC,QSA,L]

Kalle had tough me this today morning & I thought it might work for you because it worked for me. :)